# How to create function which return only even numbers in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Write a function that takes one argument, which is an array of numbers, and returns an array that contains only the numbers from the input array that are even.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step walkthrough:

1. We create 3 arrays, 1 containing only even numbers, one only containing uneven numbers, one containing both
2. We create the function **returnEvenNumbersFromArray(array)**
3. We create an empty array **finishedArray** to store the even numbers to return if the function has finished
4. We iterate over the array that was passed to the function, checking if it is even

Running `num % 2` returns a 0 (false) if the number isnt even, and a 1 (true) if it is even.

5. Every even number is pushed into our **finishedArray**
6. We return the **finishedArray**

```js
evenNumbers = [2,4,6,8,10,12,16]
unevenNumbers = [1,3,5,7,9,11,15]
mixedNumbers = [0, 1, 6, 7, 3, 14]
function returnEvenNumbersFromArray(array) {
 finishedArray = []
 array.forEach(function(num) {
   if(!(num % 2)) {
     finishedArray.push(num)
    }
  })
  return finishedArray;
}
console.log(returnEvenNumbersFromArray(evenNumbers)) 
console.log(returnEvenNumbersFromArray(unevenNumbers)) 
console.log(returnEvenNumbersFromArray(mixedNumbers))
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/filter) with condition to check number is even or not. That will give you all even elements from an array

From Documentation:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented

```js
var inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
var result = inputs.filter(x => x % 2 == 0)
console.log(result);
```

---

If you want function which takes array as input parameter and return array containing all even elements then try below

```js
const getEvenNumbers = (inputs) => inputs.filter( x => x % 2 === 0 );

console.log(getEvenNumbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

Comment: This is the best answer.   You can turn it into a function if truly needed.  `const getEvenVariables = (arrayOfNumerics) => arrayOfNumerics.filter( x => x % 2 === 0 );` but isnt necessarily needed.

Comment: @Fallenreaper, yes if needed we can turn into a function.Check my latest update

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) array methods.

**Using filter:**

```js
const onlyEven = arr => arr.filter(v => v % 2 === 0)

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

console.log(onlyEven(data))
```

**Using reduce:**

```js
const onlyEven = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => (v % 2 === 0 ? [...a, v] : a), [])

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

console.log(onlyEven(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var array = [-200, -163, -26, -4, 0, 7, 76];

var evens = array.filter((x) => {
   return x % 2 === 0;
})
```

Comment: nice lightweight solution!